# Pull-to-refresh with Knockout and JayData

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, odata, jaydata

I'm developing HTML5 app with `Knockout.js` and `JayData` and I encountered a problem while implementing a pull-to-refresh data list.

I query a remote `OData` service with `JayData` API and assign the results to a `KO observable` array:

```
db.MySet
  .orderBy('it.Field1')
  .skip(recordsToSkip)
  .take(20)
  .toArray()
  .then(function(result) {
     self.MyDataList(result);
  }
```

I always lose the old records. How could I fix my code?

---

Comment: What's the type of `result`?

Comment: It's an array of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is a small thing missing while bindig the result to the Knockout observable: check if the existing array already contains elements and append the result to the existing ones.

My colleague Viktor has a tutorial, which implements a highscore list with [Knockout+JayData pull-to-refresh](http://jaystack.com/blog/sliding-puzzle-html5-game-powered-by-jaystorm)

```
db.MySet
  .orderBy('it.Field1')
  .skip(recordsToSkip)
  .take(20)
  .toArray()
  .then(function(result) { 
     if (result.length){
       if (self.MyDataList().length){
            self.MyDataList(self.MyDataList().concat(result));
       }else{
            self.MyDataList(result);
       }
    }
   });
```

Does this fix the app?
The full context of the example can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/jaystorm/slidingpuzzle/blob/master/puzzle.js#L426)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to concatenate your new array of objects to your old list:

```
.then(function(result) {
    oldList = oldList.concat(result);
    self.MyDataList(oldList);
}
```

(So, on the first run, you will need to set `oldList = []`)

Comment: Thank you, this was the mistake

Comment: Accepting answers from involved sources is quite common. dont take it personally :)

Comment: @PeterAronZentai: I know, but that doesn't make it less annoying :-/